# jquery gallery with the Ability to change images according to button clicks events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need image gallery plugin, that has the Ability to reinitialize with different images according to clicks events.

the gallery should has thumbs and a full screen mode and well document.

for example if I press button 1 the gallery will load a set of images.

pressing button 2 will load different set of images. and so on.

any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried? where is your problem? 
You can start with the event keydown and match the char code of it to '1' / '2' etc...

Answer (score 0):

tn3Gallery

http://www.tn3gallery.com

has option for albums and can get external xml to update.

great documentation also